# Stack multiple queried Importranges with a single word between the two sets of imported data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a master sheet that contains all of the data for other sheets. Column A in the master sheet is the name for who's sheet it will import to. So if the name is "John" then every row that has "John" in column A from the master sheet will be imported into John's sheet. I have the person's name in cell G1 of their own respective sheet and use the following formula.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("LINK_TO_SHEET","Assignments!A2:Q"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 WHERE Col1='"&G1&"'",0),""))`

Master sheet looks like this:

| Assigned To | Name | State | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Blake G. | Arizona | Phoenix |
| Andy | Chase C. | Arizona | Phoenix |
| John | Amy B. | New Mexico | Santa Fe |
| John | Bill S. | Texas | Austin |

John's sheet will look like this:

| Name | State | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blake G. | Arizona | Phoenix |
| Amy B. | New Mexico | Santa Fe |
| Bill | Texas | Austin |

I want to separate the data based on what is in `Col17` and put a single word between the two data sets. Col17 has either a `Y` or a `N` so I can just add `AND Col17='N'` to the existing formula. I double up the formula, but changed the last condition to be `Col17='Y'` so that I can pull the two data sets separately and on top of each other.

`={ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("LINK_TO_SHEET","Assignments!A2:Q"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 WHERE Col1='"&G1&"' AND Col17='N'",0),""));ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("LINK_TO_SHEET","Assignments!A2:Q"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 WHERE Col1='"&G1&"' AND Col17='Y'",0),""))}`

What I want to do is add a single word between the two imported sets of data. It should like kinda like this:

| Name | State | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blake G. | Arizona | Phoenix |
| Amy B. | New Mexico | Santa Fe |
| Inactive |  |  |
| Bill | Texas | Austin |

I added the word inactive so the middle looks like `""));"Inactive";ARRAY` between the two formulas but because of how Query works I get an error saying the array lengths for each formula do not match. Is there alternative to help make this happen or will I need to figure out a workaround with something that isn't Query?

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet that contains the data of the `Col17` & `Col1`? This is to ensure we are replicating your formula correctly on our end. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION

> *Feel free to comment below if ever your question has been misunderstood.*

In my understanding, here's your process:

1. The ***first formula*** will list all data that has **N** value in `Col17` .
2. The ***second formula*** will list all data that has **Y** value in `Col17`.
3. This ***second formula*** should also have an **Inactive** title header.
4. Merge the two formulas separated by the word "**Inactive**".

If I got it correctly, you could use the `label` clause to add "**Inactive**" in your second **Query** function as seen on this tweaked formula:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET_URL","A1:Q"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 WHERE Col1 = '"&G1&"' AND Col17 = 'Y'"),0));ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET_URL","A1:Q"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 WHERE Col1 = '"&G1&"' AND Col17 = 'N' label Col2 'Inactive'"),0))}
```

### Demo

> Sample result.

[image]

> E.g. If there's new data added that should be under "**Inactive**".

[image]
***Main Sheet***

[image]
***John's Sheet***

Answer (score 1):

@SputnikDrunk2 is a very good workaround. Just in case you decide to stack different types of ranges that are not queries, you should consider that they need to have the same amount of columns. So if you add a new row it should have the 12 columns you have from your Queries. One way would be like this:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("LINK_TO_SHEET","Assignments!A2:Q"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 WHERE Col1='"&G1&"' AND Col17='N'",0),""));
{"Inactive","","","","","","","","","","",""};
ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("LINK_TO_SHEET","Assignments!A2:Q"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 WHERE Col1='"&G1&"' AND Col17='Y'",0),""))}
```

Another option to avoid creating so many "","","","" is to use this "trick" that divides a range by 0, and with IFERROR it returns empty cells:

`{"Inactive",INDEX (IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1,11)/0,))};`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
=lambda(z,
          {filter(choosecols(z,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13),index(z,,1)=A1,index(z,,17)="N");
          {"Inactive",makearray(1,11,lambda(r,c,iferror(1/0)))};
          filter(choosecols(z,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13),index(z,,1)=A1,index(z,,17)="Y")}
)(A1:Q4)
```

- `A1:Q4` part in the formula should be replaced with your importrange Fx
- `2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13` part can also be replaced with shorter `sequence(1,12,2,1)`

[image]